# Night buses from Bangkok to Hua Hin

Tags: buses, thailand, bangkok

I desire to get from Bangkok to Hua Hin by bus only and with lowering the chance for traffic jams as much as possible, hence I desire a night bus.

From a search query *night bus to Hua Hin* I found data which I recognized as perhaps outdated or unclear about when night buses from Bangkok *Eastern bus terminal (Ekkamai)* to Hua Hin are available and how much time should arrival take (3 hours, 4 hours, 5 hours).

By "night bus" I mean to a direct bus (no intermediate stops) with which it is extremely unlikely to be stuck in a traffic jams due to departing at:

```
24:00 or 24:30
01:00 or 01:30
02:00 or 02:30
03:00 or 03:30
```

Are there such daily buses from Bangkok?

Comment: Does it need to be from Ekkamai? Does it need to be a night bus, or do you simply want to avoid traffic jams or intermediate stops? What about taking the train?

Comment: @MichaelHampton AFAIK it has to be from Ekkamai; only night bus; other ways to avoiding traffic jams are not for me in this case; no intermediate stops ;  no train.

Comment: I poked around a bit on 12go.asia but I was not able to find any departures from Ekkamai to Hua Hin after 19:00 or before 05:00. Maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Most buses to Hua Hin leave not from Ekkamai, but from the **New Southern Bus Terminal** (*Sai Tai Mai*).  However, Sai Tai Mai is in far western Bangkok a solid 10 km from the city center and not reachable by BTS/MRT, so you're likely to run into traffic jams just trying to get there...

I know you said "bus only", but I would still recommend the train.  Trains to Hua Hin depart from Hualamphong (Bangkok's main station) roughly hourly, you can take a daytime train without fear of jams, and Hualamphong is easily reached by MRT.

Comment: Googling Sai Tai Mai brings me to the Ekkamai station; I suggest to edit to clarify you meant to that station which is about 2 minutes walk from Ekkamai BTS, or you meant something else?

Comment: I take line 40 from Ramkhamaeng to Hualamphong, I think it's a low priced good option.

Comment: @JohnDoea [Try Google Maps instead?](https://goo.gl/maps/Z7uHR1v1JJ7gsKKM8)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't answer my question but it's quite close; there are vans going out of Ekammai bus terminal in 05:00,

quite close to 03:00 but not the same effect of course:

https://12go.asia/en/travel/bangkok/hua-hin